# PHP check if the minutes of the current time are greater than a variable value

Tags: php, time, range

I have to check, starting from a range of times (start and end), if the current time is included in the interval (and this is done)

```
// Time intervall
$range = 30;

// Time range
$start = strtotime('09:00:00');
$end = strtotime('13:00:00');

// Now
$time = time();


if($time >= $start && $time <= $end):
    
    echo 'Inside range';

else:
    
    echo 'Outside range';

endif;
```

Now I have to check if the minutes, including seconds, are greater than the variable that contains the minutes of interval.

Example: if it is 10:31:23 and my time variable is 30 minutes, I have to check if (minutes:seconds) 31:23 is greater or less than the variable, that is 30 minutes, if it is greater I have to add to the hour (10), the double the variable, that is 30 * 2 and thus obtain 11:00:00, if instead it is less I have to add only 30 to the hour, therefore 10:30:00.

Comment: Well, and what if the time variable is 15 minutes?

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: The time variable can only be 20, 30 or 60 minutes, my question is how to achieve this

Comment: how to check if the minutes and seconds of the time are greater or less and then on this basis add the time variable

Comment: Why not write some code to achieve this? Why not compare the variables properly?

Comment: Because if I had an idea I would have put it into action ... I'm here to ask for help, not necessarily the code ready, even an idea of ​​how to try, because I repeat ... if I knew I would not have asked you not it seems

Comment: With which part are you struggling? Reading the minutes from the current time? `date('i')` might help

Comment: No it doesn't help, until I get there...

Comment: As said before: how to check if the minutes and seconds of the time are greater or less and then on this basis add the time variable

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not write down the different cases in terms of unit tests, and then implement them? Looks like a perfect exercise for TDD to me